# Arraylist that each object within knows about the other objects in the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a small game where there is a zombie fish that Infects other fish. I have that part completed but I want the fish to be able to infect others but doing that, I will need each fish in the arrayList to know about the other fish to be able to infect them. This is the main part of my panel that creates the the arrayList.

Basic Layout:
I have a panel that handles all objects of the game.
That panel then calls the fish class to create a fish
The panel contains the ArrayList of Fish. 
I pass it to the zombie fish as a paramater and within there I process the array for the initial infection

What I want to happen after that, is all the fish that get infected by them also gain the ability to infect others. I need a way to allow the fish in the ArrayList to know about each other in the parent class to be able to write the code for them to infect.

Comment: not enough detail to receive an adequate answer. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Infecting other fish**
In that case make ArrayList of ZFish as well, every time you infect fish, you remove it from ArrayList of Fish and make new instance of ZFish on position of infected fish. Example:

```
private ArrayList<Fish> _fish; 
private ArrayList<ZFish> _zfish; 

fishInfectedMethod(int indexOfCaughtFish){
    int x = _fish.get(indexOfCaughtFish).getX();
    int y = _fish.get(indexOfCaughtFish).getY();
    _fish.remove(indexOfCaughtFish);
    _zfish.add(new ZFish(new Color(0, 179, 60),_tank, _fish));
    _zfish.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

Assuming that you have getters for fish location.

Comment: I have that part completed but I want to go a step further to make normal fish have the ablility to infect others once infected.

Comment: I didn't understand you well, I updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, this works great!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the fish class your current class to achieve this. i would do it like this:

```
public int _numFish = 100;  //CHANGE IT TO PUBLIC its important
public ArrayList<Fish> _fish; 

_fish = new ArrayList<Fish>();
for(int i=0;i<_numFish;i++)
    _fish.add(new Fish(setRandColor(), _tank, this));

for(int i=0;i<_numFish;i++)
    _fish.add(new MotleyFish(setRandColor(),setRandColor(),_tank,this));

for(Fish f: _fish)
    f.setLocation((int)(Math.random() *(TANK_WIDTH - TANK_X + 1)+TANK_X), 
              (int)(Math.random() *(TANK_HEIGHT - TANK_Y + 1)+ TANK_Y));

_shark = new ZFish(new Color(0, 179, 60),_tank, _fish,this);
_shark.setLocation((int)(Math.random() *(TANK_WIDTH - TANK_X + 1)+TANK_X), 
              (int)(Math.random() *(TANK_HEIGHT - TANK_Y + 1)+ TANK_Y));
```

Recognize the **this** at the end of every Initialization of a Fish.

Then in your Fish class:

```
public Fish(Color color,Tank _tank, YourMainClassName class ){
   //now you can access _fish with class._fish
   //and _numFish with class._numFish
}
```

Comment: Will this work if it creates the first fish, passes the class into that fish and then creates another fish after that which knows about the first but none after because the fish are created after the class is passed?

Comment: It is only a reference to your Panel class, so it can read the data from there. class._fish is only a reference to the _fish array in the main method, and you can access it in your constructor. To use it over all, you have to create a classwide YourMainClassName class variable, and then in your constructor call : this.class = class. Then you can use it in every function of the Fish class, and it will always have the same state as in your Panel class. Note you have to change YourMainClassName with your classname ^^

Answer (score 0):

One option is to reorganize your fish classes so they all implement an interface, say `Fish`, then call your classes `GenericFish`, `MotleyFish`, and `ZFish`.

Then instead of having constants for locations and housing them in each `Fish` instance, have a `Grid` class that houses a 2D array of `Fish` references.  The 2D array acts like your coordinates, and the `Grid` class houses that array as well as other utility methods.  You can house a `move` method inside either the `Fish` implementations, which passes a reference to the grid, or house it within the `Grid` class, which moves fish around.

You could then have a method on the `Grid` class that takes in a grid location and will return a list of nearby fish by checking nearby coordinates that house `Fish` instances.